# Error: Ezjsonm.Parse_error(870828711, "JSON.of_buffer expected JSON text (JSON value)") while importing a snaptshot

Tags: node, baker, error, setup, snapshots

I'm writing this error because there isn't any updated information about it.

I previously have problems with a baker that I have setted on mainnet and there was a downtime for days, the node wasn't running properly so I decided to try sync again from a recent snapshot.

I've tried 3 different snapshots from marigold and from https://lambsonacid.nl/ and after download the snapshot and try the command:

`./octez-node snapshot import <name-of-the-file>`

I'm getting this error:
`Ezjsonm.Parse_error(870828711, "JSON.of_buffer expected JSON text (JSON value)")`

I've try giving and not giving it a name to the imported file, adding the $path(pwd), adding to the command the flag --block, pull the branch latest-release, make building again and nothing seems to work.

What I haven't try is to create and endorsments file as it is the solution for this other issue: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/314 but as it is from years ago I'm not sure if it would work or affect anything, the other thing that I haven't try is running the commands:
 `opam switch remove .` and  `rm -rf _opam _build` as describe here:
https://opentezos.com/deploy-a-node/installation/#from-scratch I would like to know if it's safe (or makes sense) to try those.

because it was already upgraded it and it was working.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by removing the previous node. I'm pretty sure I ran that command  before so if you are with the same problem you could check by doing it again.

```
rm -rf ~/.tezos-node
```

then running the command again.